# PHP sort the number without using ORDER by DESC/ASC

Tags: php, sorting

is there a possible way to sort the number with something below

```
GameID   Turn   
3         2
6         1
7         2
5         2
8         0
9         1

return should be { for example GameID 6 is TURN for the Game or Left in the Game }
GameID   Turn
6         1
9         1
8         0
3         2
5         2
7         2

another example { for example GameID 7 is TURN for the Game or Left in the Game }
GameID   Turn
7         2
3         2
5         2
8         0
9         1
6         1
```

that was just a sample that i need to figure out.
Is that possible to sort the Turn?

I can't use the ORDER BY turn DESC/ASC
Because what order by doing is just something like this `2 1 0` while ASC `0 1 2` bu what i need to figure out is that to sort this way { we have 0 1 2 } now if we starts at `2` then the sort should be something like this `2 0 1` or if we starts at turn 1 the sorts should be this way `1 2 0`

i hope something get my point...

please i already used asort but its not fit. is there any other php function for sorting?

thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `ORDER BY FIELD`:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM table
ORDER BY FIELD(Turn, 1, 0, 2) ASC
 --                           DESC
```

Comment: @EugenRieck It can be automated with PHP - some rules have to be written.

Comment: One of the reasons I gave the +1!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  GameID,Turn
FROM yourtableorview
WHERE yourcriteria
ORDER BY IF(Turn<$startturn,Turn+99999999,Turn)
```